# google script fetch bombs on URL with "^"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some reason both of these work:

```
var fetchString="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=1&b=4&c=2011&d=1e=4&f=2013&g=d"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString)


var fetchString="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=1&b=4&c=2011&d=1e=4&f=2013&g=d"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString)
```

but this doesn't work:

```
var fetchString="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC&a=1&b=4&c=2011&d=1e=4&f=2013&g=d"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString)
```

this doesn't work also:

```
var fetchString="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^HSI&a=1&b=4&c=2011&d=1e=4&f=2013&g=d"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString)
```

It seems the "^" is throwing it off? But if you paste that url into any browser the data comes over. Anybody know what's going here?

Could this be a bug?

Comment: The most likely cause is you need to encode it to %5E

Comment: wow. that worked! how do i give you credit for it Jay?

Comment: @jason_cant_code Mark Jay Gilford's comment up to give him credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) specification:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

If you encode the special characters other than listed above & reserved characters, it will work. Browsers do this automatically.

Here is a working code.

```
var fetchString="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+encodeURIComponent('^')+"HSI&a=1&b=4&c=2011&d=1e=4&f=2013&g=d";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchString);
```